# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.text.Layout.getLineCount()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, android-handler

I am getting null pointer exception randomly, usually it works and sometime it crashes, I had searched a lot but didn't get any help as it there is no proper line from where I get any help,

I am also using handler with it.

My logcat error is as follows and code is added below it,

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.text.Layout.getLineCount()' on a null object reference
 at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6703)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
 at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my code as follows, here it usually crash on click of register or forget button on first install and after that it usually works fine but sometime it gives me error,

```java
 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,ProcessedResult
 {
    private Handler uiThreadHandler;
    private Context context;
    private EditText ed_password,ed_Username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

      StorageManager storageManager=new StorageManager(this,"abc");
                    String accessTokenCheck=storageManager.getValue(Constants.SharedPreferences.LACCESSTOKEN, null);
      if(accessTokenCheck!=null)
                        GeneralFunctions.moveToNextActivity(MainActivity.class,this);

      uiThreadHandler = new UIThreadHandler();
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             init();
         }
        }).start();
       }

       //Initialization part
       private final void init()
       {
          context=this;

          FontsManager.initFormAssets(this, "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
          FontsManager.changeFonts(this);

          TextView myTextView =  GeneralFunctions.findViewByIdAndCast(this, R.id.login_tv_noAccount);
          myTextView.setMovementMethod(new LinkTouchMovementMethod());
                    myTextView.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
          SpannableString mySpannable = new SpannableString(myTextView.getText().toString());

          TouchableSpan touchableSpan = new TouchableSpan(Color.parseColor("#606060"),getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlue),Color.TRANSPARENT) {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View textView) {
                            GeneralFunctions.simpleMoveToNextActivity(Register.class, context);
                        }
                    };

          mySpannable.setSpan(touchableSpan, GeneralFunctions.getText(myTextView).indexOf("Register"), GeneralFunctions.getText(myTextView).length(), 0);
          myTextView.setText(mySpannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

          TextView tv_forgetPassword =  GeneralFunctions.findViewByIdAndCast(this,R.id.login_tv_foregetPassword);
                    GeneralFunctions.setTextColorSelector(Color.parseColor("#606060"),getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlue),tv_forgetPassword);
                    tv_forgetPassword.setOnClickListener(this);

          ed_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_ed_password);
          ed_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_ed_usrName);
          ed_password.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());

          Button bt_Login= GeneralFunctions.findViewByIdAndCast(this,R.id.login_bt_signin);
                    setSelector(R.drawable.big_green_btn_normal, bt_Login);

          Button bt_linkedInd= GeneralFunctions.findViewByIdAndCast(this,R.id.login_bt_linkedin);
                    setSelector(R.drawable.big_blue_btn_normal, bt_linkedInd);
          }

          private final void setSelector(final int resourceId,final Button button)
          {
              button.setOnClickListener(this);
              try
              {
                String name = getNameofResyrce(activity,resourceId);
                String newString=name.replace("normal","pressed");

                StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
                states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, getDrawablebyName(activity,newString));
                states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},getDrawablebyName(activity, newString));
                states.addState(new int[]{}, getDrawablebyName(activity, name));
                if(view instanceof Button)
                   ((Button)view).setBackground(states);
                else
                   if(view instanceof ImageView)
                       ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(states);
               } catch (Exception e)
               {
               }
          }


                public static synchronized Drawable getDrawablebyName(Context context,String name)
                {
                    Resources resources = context.getResources();
                    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                    return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId())
                    {
                        case R.id.login_bt_linkedin:
                        {
                            DWebView transparentDialog = DWebView.newInstance();
                            showProgressDialog(transparentDialog, Constants.DialogConstants.WEB);
                        }
                        break;
                        case R.id.login_bt_signin:
                            uiThreadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.VALIDATION);
                            break;
                        case R.id.login_tv_foregetPassword:
                            GeneralFunctions.simpleMoveToNextActivity_Without_history(ForgetPassword.class, context);
                            break;
                    }
                }

        //Listener part
                @Override
                public <IResponse, IMethod> void processedResult(IResponse iResponse, IMethod iMethod) {
                    switch (iMethod.toString())
                    {
                        case "back":
                            finish();
                            break;
                        case "showProgress":
                         uiThreadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.SHOWDIALOG);
                            break;
                        case "hideProgress":
                            uiThreadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.HIDEDIALOG);
                            break;
                    }
                }


        //Handler part
                private class UIThreadHandler extends Handler {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                    {
                        switch (msg.what) {
                            case Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.SETERROR:
                            {
                                CustomException exception=(CustomException)msg.obj;
                                TextView editText=exception.getTextView();
                                editText.setError(exception.getMessage());
                                editText.setFocusable(true);
                                editText.requestFocus();
                            }
                            break;
                            case Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.HIDEDIALOG:
                                hideProgressDialog(Constants.DialogConstants.Transparent);
                                break;
                            case Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.SHOWDIALOG: {
                                DTDialog dtDialog=DTDialog.newInstance();
                                showProgressDialog(dtDialog,Constants.DialogConstants.Transparent);
                            }
                            break;
                            case Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.VALIDATION: {
    //Here validation is done in separate thread
                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            if (Validation.validate(Login.this))
                                                GeneralFunctions.moveToNextActivity(MainActivity.class, context);
                                        } catch (CustomException e)
                                            {
    //Catch exception for validation is thrown here
                                                Message message = uiThreadHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.SETERROR);
                                                message.obj=e;
                                                uiThreadHandler.sendMessage(message);
                                            }finally {
                                                uiThreadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.ActivityBasicsCode.HIDEDIALOG);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).start();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            super.handleMessage(msg);
                        }
                    }

                public final<T extends DialogFragment> void showProgressDialog(T currentDialog,String tagName)
                {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
                    currentDialog.show(fragmentManager, tagName);
                }

                public final void hideProgressDialog(String tagName)
                {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
                    DialogFragment transparentDialog = (DialogFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tagName);
                    if (transparentDialog == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    transparentDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView style="@style/imageview"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <EditText
        android:tag="@string/login_emailId_phone"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        style="@style/edittext"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:id="@+id/login_ed_emailPhone"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <EditText
        android:tag="@string/login_password"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:id="@+id/login_ed_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/login_password"
        style="@style/edittext"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_11sdp"
        android:id="@+id/login_tv_foregetPassword"
        android:text="@string/login_forgetPassword"
        style="@style/textView"
        android:textColor="#606060"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:id="@+id/login_bt_signin"
        style="@style/button"
        android:text="@string/login_singin"
        android:background="@drawable/big_green_btn_normal"
        />

    <cl.tempclick.ui.custom_view.LineThroughTextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        app:android_textColor="#606060"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:lineHeight="@dimen/_2sdp"
        app:lineColor="@color/colorGray"
        app:android_textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
        app:android_text="@string/login_or"
        app:textPadding="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:id="@+id/login_bt_linkedin"
        style="@style/button"
        android:text="@string/login_linkedin"
        android:background="@drawable/big_blue_btn_normal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:id="@+id/login_tv_noAccount"
        android:text="@string/login_noAccount"
        style="@style/textView"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#606060"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"/>

</LinearLayout>
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/login_vs_empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout="@layout/empty_view" />
```

Comment: show the code of your invoked activity

Comment: its a `java.lang.NullPointerException` which means the you are trying to use a object or widget which is not yet initialized. show your code.

Comment: share your code if you want any help

Comment: @mangusta,@AnswerDroid, i had shared my code and sorry as the code is not well formatted and thanks for your help ..

Comment: please help me guys...i am stuck here

Comment: can you put layout.xml of this activity? so i can check!

Comment: @Survivor, i am made my all effort to paste it here but failed so u can acces it from the following link, https://drive.google.com/a/studiotamba.com/file/d/0BwiBPe16lODTdS1CVFloZXR5T1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @VikramSingh without an access how can download?

Comment: @Survivor please use this link,https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwkVxZWl7VcESGZ6RV94MFdzams/view?usp=sharing ,no request is needed after this

Comment: @Trush, you can find the LineThroughTextView through the following link, https://gist.github.com/TheGreat0004/b0c0c5d80004b2d40eec

Comment: Even if it is due to threading, then the error must be something like this "Only the parent or main thread can touch it's views", so it's irrelogical that it is due to threading

Comment: try cleaning your project, and also why is it that for you editextexs you did not use findViewAndCast method ??

Comment: @Elltz, current it is just on click and random, i will code it later that's why i hadn't initialized it till now.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be calling `init()` (or *any* code that touches the Android UI) in a non-UI thread.

Comment: that didn't make any difference

Comment: As a new Android dev I always forget that I should not touch UI stuff in a non UI thread, I always do the set of the UI components in the same thread of the DB, now I know why sometimes I get this weird errors. Thx

Answer (score 1):

you must call textview `getLayout()` after the textview measure ,so it's better to call `getLayout()` in

```
textview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textview.getLayout()....
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `thread.join()` method, in which you are calling `init()` method.

Answer (score -1):

I think the error came from this line

```
mySpannable.setSpan(touchableSpan, GeneralFunctions.getText(myTextView).indexOf("Register"), GeneralFunctions.getText(myTextView).length(), 0);
```

try to logout you get the index value & textview text from 
gettext(textview) & indexOf() method.

Comment: @Moblie Application Develo, thanks for the reply, but can u elaborate it as event if it is due to thing then there must be some line number in exception log cat...and as i said that's random. sometime it works and sometime it gives crash.

Comment: can i see your GeneralFunctions code to gettext & indexof.?

Comment: You try to pass static value in length & check

mySpannable.setSpan(touchableSpan, 0, myTextView.getText().length(), 0);

Comment: public static<T> String getText(T editText)
    {
        if(editText instanceof EditText)
            return ((EditText)editText).getText().toString();
        else if((editText instanceof Button))
            return ((Button)editText).getText().toString();
        else if((editText instanceof TextView))
            return ((TextView)editText).getText().toString();
        return null;
    }

Comment: This is General functions method getText, and indexof is a inbuilt method of String in java or andorid

Comment: can i see your @style/textView Code

Comment: <style name="textView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_15sdp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>